# What is the difference between NumPy object methods and NumPy function calls?

Tags: python, function, numpy, methods

If I have a NumPy array,

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
```

what is the difference between getting information about that array using the object method

```
>>> x.mean()
4.5
```

compared to using the NumPy functions

```
>>> np.mean(x)
4.5
```

I expect the object method is calling the function, but there are examples where a function is not included as an method, such as

```
>>> np.median(x)
4.5
>>> x.median()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'
```

The exclusion of some functions seems to indicate a functional approach is more complete or preferred to the object oriented approach because it eliminates the need to switch back and forth.  Is the exclusion of some methods intentional?  Is there an inherent advantage for one approach compared to the other?

Comment: There isn't systematic difference or relation.  Most of the functions are written in Python which you can read.  Many delegate the action to the corresponding method if it exists.  The function form can also convert a list into an array before acting on it.  The method call is usually a bit faster because it involves one less layer of calling.

Comment: There are also operators (which translate into method calls), `ufuncs` (which may take several arrays), and functions that take lists of arrays.  Keep in mind that `numpy` has a long history, and many contributors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a notable difference between `numpy.sort` and `ndarray.sort`: the former returns a copy of the array, the latter sorts in-place.

For other methods, one can use equivalent functions just as well. The function form will accept array-like collections that can be converted to a NumPy array; this is sometimes convenient. On the other hand, this comes at the expense of a few more checks and function calls, so the method form should be a tiny bit faster. In practice, this is probably negligible; for me the deciding factor is usually that methods take fewer characters to type.

Some mathematical operations are more naturally written as methods: compare `np.transpose(A)` and `A.T`, when A is a 2-dimensional array.